# I'm new to Volley Networking library and facing this problem java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: pthread_create (1040KB stack) failed: Try again

Tags: kotlin, android-volley

```
  class RequestQueueClass constructor(context: Context) {
    companion object {
        @Volatile
        private var INSTANCE: RequestQueueClass? = null

        fun getInstance(context: Context) =
                INSTANCE ?: synchronized(this) {
                    INSTANCE ?: RequestQueueClass(context)
                }
    }

    val requestQueue: RequestQueue by lazy {
        // applicationContext is key, it keeps you from leaking the
        // Activity or BroadcastReceiver if someone passes one in.
        Volley.newRequestQueue(context.applicationContext)

    }

    fun <T> addToRequestQueue(req: Request<T>) {

        requestQueue.add(req)


    }
}
```

I'm declaring a singleton volley request handler class and accessing it everywhere but the problem is how to make the request null after calling inside the lazy?

Answer (score 1):

I realize I'm a little late to this question, but here's my 2 cents worth:

I see that you're not actually initializing your INSTANCE object so everytime you access the getInstance method, you are creating a new queue with the application context which is why you probably got the out of memory error since initializing the request queue takes a significant amount of memory